# Request Times Out while uploading large size files to the server using ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I have developed an ios app and for making server requests I am using ASIHTTPRequest. The issue which I am facing is the server Request times out when I try to upload large size files. I have tried both the SetData and SetFile methods for it but the issue is the same on both of them. I an unable to resolve it. It has eaten my four days. My code is given below. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)syncTaskOnTheServer:(Tasks *)task ofTheUser:(NSString *)userId{

    __block unsigned long long uploaded = 0;
    ASIFormDataRequest *syncTask = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@tasks",baseurl]]];
    syncTask.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;
    [syncTask addPostValue:userId forKey:@"UserId"];
    [syncTask addPostValue:appId forKey:@"AppId"];
    [syncTask addPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",task.taskTitle]    forKey:@"Title"];
    [syncTask addPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",task.notes]        forKey:@"Description"];
    [syncTask addPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",task.priority]     forKey:@"Priority"];
    [syncTask addPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",task.taskCategory] forKey:@"TaskCategory"];
    [syncTask addPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",task.creationDate]] forKey:@"CreationDate"];
    syncTask.shouldUseRFC2616RedirectBehaviour = YES;

    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    if (![task.imagePath isEqualToString:@"No Image Attached"]) {
        NSString *imageFilePath =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_image.jpg",path,task.taskurlSubPart];
        UIImage *image          =  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
        NSData *imageData       =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        NSLog(@"\n%@\n",task.taskurlSubPart);
        [syncTask setData:imageData withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",task.taskurlSubPart ] andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"Image"];
        /*
         [syncTask setFile:imageFilePath withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",task.taskurlSubPart] andContentType:@"image/jpeg"  forKey:@"Image"];
         */
    }

    if (![task.audioURL isEqualToString:@"No Audio File"]) {
        NSMutableString *audioFileName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:task.audioFileName];
        [audioFileName appendString:@".caf"];
        NSString *audioFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf",path,task.audioFileName];
        NSData *audioData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath]];
        [syncTask setData:audioData withFileName:audioFileName andContentType:@"audio/x-caf" forKey:@"Audio"];
    }

    [syncTask setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [syncTask setStartedBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"start block");
    }];
    [syncTask setFailedBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"\n%@\n",[syncTask error]);
        NSString *serverResponse = [syncTask responseString];
        WLParseServerResponse *parseResponse = [[WLParseServerResponse alloc] init];
        [parseResponse parseSyncTaskResponse:serverResponse forTask:task];
        [parseResponse release];

    }];
    [syncTask setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *serverResponse = [syncTask responseString];
        NSLog(@"\nserver response: %@\n",serverResponse);
        WLParseServerResponse *parseResponse = [[WLParseServerResponse alloc] init];
        [parseResponse parseSyncTaskResponse:serverResponse forTask:task];
        [parseResponse release];
    }];
    [syncTask setHeadersReceivedBlock:^(NSDictionary *responseHeaders) {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseHeaders);
    }];
    [syncTask setBytesSentBlock:^(unsigned long long size, unsigned long long total) {
        uploaded += size;
        NSLog(@"%llu, %llu", uploaded, total);

    }];
    [syncTask startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: Your backend platform PHP/.NET/etc ?

Comment: Check your PHP ini file of "upload_max_filesize"

Comment: Or print phpinfo(); // Shows all information, find "upload_max_filesize"

Answer (score 0):

Add this,

[syncTask setTimeOutSeconds:45];  // 45 seconds, it may differ according to the file size

set your maximum seconds that you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have tried this too.Doing so the file uploading restarts after a particular time and time out eventually

Answer (score 0):

The problem may occur under different circumstances, You might find it useful by trying the  following steps

```
Step 1 - If your using PHP backend service (Check your PHP INI file)
```

Of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 50M
```

> Step 2 - Test the same upload file via rest client

[Mozilla Add-ons RestClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)

[Chrome Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Comment: I think through RestClient one can test those requests which are in the form of Json. My request is multipart, can a multipart request be tested on RestClient? If yes than tell me the way I can do it plz. Thanks

Comment: First can you check your PHP ini file of "upload_max_filesize"

Comment: yes it's maximum size is far greater than the files I am trying to upload